# Can't find setsebool / getsebool in Fedora 20

Tags: symlink, selinux, fedora20

Due to SELinux keeps preventing symlinks in `/var/www/html/` to `/home/<user>/path/to/project/`in Fedora 20, I have to use `setsebool` / `getsebool` to let SELinux allow httpd to enable homedirs (using `$ setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1` according to sealert). But it seems that Fedora 20 doesn't have this tool installed.. I only got `command not found...`, and I can't find in which package those tools ships with, so I can `yum install` it..

Are those tools obsolete or do I have to install additional package? Another suggestions to solve the `symlinks` issue (no, I don't accept `$ sudo chmod` or whatsoever has to do with changing permissions) are welcome too.

---

**Answer**

It seems that you have to log in to the terminal as root, in case you have `policycoreutils` already installed:

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for <root username>:
$ getsebool <whatever>
$ setsebool <stuffs>
```

Comment: really? The answer provided by @TomH wasn't good enough, so you learned that you need root privileges to execute the commands provided by Tom, and you created "your own answer" within the question itself? Really?

Comment: (1) Where did you read that the answer of @TomH wasn't "good enough"? (2) I found out the solution by myself, shortly after I posted this question (I was actually waiting for response). But StackOverflow doesn't allow you to post an answer so fast after you've posted a question, moreover, StackOverflow even suggested to put the answer in the question area. And besides (3) The answer provided by @TomH is a solution, however, I already had `policecoreutils` installed, so I thought my answer would help others on track too :)

Answer (score 5):

They're in the `policycoreutils` package, which you can install with `yum`:

```
sudo yum install policycoreutils
```

Alternatively, an easy way to install a file when you don't know what package it's in is to just ask to install the file, for example:

```
sudo yum install /usr/sbin/setsebool
```

Comment: I've already `policycoreutils` installed.. However, I stumbled upon the answer, I've modified the question by adding the answer. However, thanks for the `yum` trick when not knowing the packagename, didn't know that one.

Comment: Well that's not really the answer ;-) The answer is just that they are in `/sbin` not `/bin` and you apparently don't have that on your path, but it is on your root user's path.